# How can I change permissions of a folder, including its enclosed files and subdirectories?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

I need to recursively change the permissions of all folders, sub-folders and files from within `~/.local/share/Trash/expunged` Does anyone have a clue or idea on how to do this?

[image]

I have tried following the instructions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30629/how-can-i-recursively-change-the-permissions-of-files-and-directories) but to no avail.  `chmod -R ug+rw <foldername>` doesn't seem to be working for this folder, its subdirectories, or enclosed files.

[image]

Does anyone know the `chmod` command to change these permissions? For example:

```
root@santos:/home/santos/.local/share/Trash# ls -l
total 12
drwx------ 3 santos santos 4096 Mar 21 21:38 expunged
drwx------ 2 santos santos 4096 Mar 21 21:38 files
drwx------ 2 santos santos 4096 Mar 21 21:38 info
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try by using numeric values

```
chmod -R 660 directorymainname
```

Comment: That will remove the execute bit from all directories in the specified tree, for all users, which will [prevent anybody from entering the directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Permissions).

Answer (score 12):

From the screenshot it seems like the chmod command worked well. As you wrote `chmod -R ug+rw` it gave a read/write permission to the user and group of the recursive folders.

If you want to give everybody a read/write permission you should add 'a' to your command so that it will be `chmod -R uga+rw`.

Comment: Actually, `o` means "other users." `a` is short for `ugo`. `uga+rw` is equivalent to `ugo+rw`, but they're only equivalent when `u` and `g` are specified.

Comment: actually "**a**" means "**all**" (which should be the default). the letter "**o**" is for "**other**". unless your referring to using the "**o**" in addition to another permission and not trying to define the ownership.