# Using Hard disk partion of windows

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, ntfs, read-only

From my dual booted system I'm not able to write and edit the files in the hard disk partition which was created in Windows. I have checked the permissions but it looks to be fine. 
I can only read the files from that partition from Ubuntu but not able to edit and change it. Can anyone help me out regarding this issue?

[image: Sample output of ls -ln ls -ln /path/to/file of non-writable file]

[image: Output of cat /proc/mounts]

Comment: Did you restart your pc into ubuntu or you did a shutdown followed by powerup?

Comment: I face this problem for both options

Comment: mount the windows partition in read write. sudo mount -o remount, rw /dev/sdaY /media/username/mountpoint

Comment: Ok. Will try this

Comment: Can you please tell me for what -o is used? It shows as it is invalid option

Comment: the -o is used for a comma separated list of mount options; remount and rw. post the output of  `cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: I was not aware that it has options to set permissions for enclosed files separately.  Now I see that it is read only but when i try to change it it shows setting permissions and then terminates without any warning

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `cat /proc/mounts` and `ls -ln /path/to/file` for one or more of the non-writeable files in question? Thanks.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

It's a read-only file system. Even if you have write permissions, it won't work, as the file system is mounted read-only. Maybe the file system is in an unclean state? It used to be that it refused to mount automatically, suggesting manually mounting read-only. Maybe that changed.

Boot Windows and run filesystem checks on the ntfs partitions. Make sure you shutdown Windows completely, unmounting all file systems. Linux can't mount ntfs partitions if Windows is (semi-)hibernated.
Have a look here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342159

For changing permission of folders including its enclosed file. See this Question [How can I change permissions of a folder, including its enclosed files and subdirectories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114823/how-can-i-change-permissions-of-a-folder-including-its-enclosed-files-and-subdi)

Comment: It's not read only. I checked it.

Comment: Your situation looks a bit weird.Is your system showing any message or anything else when you are trying to make changes.

Comment: Check the permissions in properties of your disk both in Windows and Ubuntu.Try to copy or delete files using sudo command in terminal.

Comment: Actually now i found out that the permission of enclosed files in the partition was read only. But when i try to change those permissions it shows setting permissions and then terminates without changing the permissions and also without any warning

Comment: Check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/114823/how-can-i-change-permissions-of-a-folder-including-its-enclosed-files-and-subdi

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're running Windows 8 or higher. If that's the case, you need to disable Fast Startup (or some similar name, as they call it).

Comment: Yes im using windows 10

Comment: Fast boot is already disabled