# Change Folder/File Permissions for HIDDEN Subdirectories

Tags: command-line, permissions, chown, hidden-files

This question is very similar to [Change Folder & File Permissions for all Subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348311/change-folder-file-permissions-for-all-subdirectories) , which worked for me completely when the folders weren't hidden. However, I have a hidden folder (call it /.hidden/) with *many* subdirectories, most of which have permissions set for root and not my_username. I want to change the permissions of all these subdirectories at once, if possible. However, if I cd /.hidden/ and then type "sudo chown my_username:my_username *", none of the file or folder permissions get changed, presumably because they're still considered "hidden" by the command even though I can see them. Anyone know an easy way around this?

Comment: Do you want to change the permission only on the directories or files too? Also are the subdirectories also hidden?

Comment: All files and subdirectories in /.hidden/ are also hidden. I want to change the owner of every file and subdirectory in /.hidden/ to my_username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-R` flag, which will recurse into every subdirectory. For example, running `sudo chown -R my_username:my_username .hidden` will make `.hidden` and all subdirectories owned by you.

The `*` glob doesn't match any hidden directories (directories starting with a `.`).