# How do I specify folders only for chmod

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

I have a 30GB website, with loads of folders, and files. I want all the folders to have the permission 745 and all the files to have 644. I tried using `chmod -R 745 public_html/` but all the sub files get that permission. 
How can I change all the folders (only) to this permission with chmod?

Comment: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/30629/how-can-i-recursively-change-the-permissions-of-files-and-directories

Comment: 745 is a typo I hope...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you delibaretely not want the group members to access the directory (will be a unusual case), you should use `755` for directories.

You can use `find`.

For files :

```
find /path/to/public_html/ -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

For directories (using 755) :

```
find /path/to/public_html/ -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
```

- `-type f` will only find the files and execute `chmod 0644` accordingly
- `-type d` will find the directories only and execute `chmod 0755` on them.